# Create gridview with some columns pre-populated

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I am trying to create a `gridview` where initially the serial number column and second column [PRODUCTS] data should be filled already i.e. on page load and other columns will have textboxes. Please refer to the picture for the grid view structure.

Then the user will fill data on the respective text boxes in reference to the second column data. How can I create such grid view?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example of such `gridview`. It is just hardcode data you may want add data from `database`. If you fetch data from `database` you can use a `loop` to populate the data.

`aspx` page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFabricDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SL">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLot" TabIndex="2" Text='<%# Bind("SL") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PRODUCTS">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtArt" TabIndex="3" Text='<%# Bind("PRODUCTS") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBalance" TabIndex="8" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Producer">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQTY" TabIndex="9" Text='<%# Bind("Producer") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Here is the method to add `row` to `gridview`

```
private void FirstGridViewRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        DataRow dr1 = null;
        DataRow dr2 = null;
        DataRow dr3 = null;
        DataRow dr4 = null;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SL", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PRODUCTS", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Producer", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr2 = dt.NewRow();
        dr3 = dt.NewRow();
        dr4 = dt.NewRow();

        dr["SL"] = 1;
        dr["PRODUCTS"] = "A";
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Producer"] = string.Empty;

        dr1["SL"] = 2;
        dr1["PRODUCTS"] = "B";
        dr1["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr1["Producer"] = string.Empty;

        dr2["SL"] = 3;
        dr2["PRODUCTS"] = "C";
        dr2["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr2["Producer"] = string.Empty;

        dr3["SL"] = 4;
        dr3["PRODUCTS"] = "D";
        dr3["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr3["Producer"] = string.Empty;

        dr4["SL"] = 5;
        dr4["PRODUCTS"] = "E";
        dr4["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr4["Producer"] = string.Empty;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr2);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr3);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr4);
        //ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;  if you want to get previous state keep it in viewstate

        gvFabricDetails.DataSource = dt;
        gvFabricDetails.DataBind();
    }
```

Now you can call the method in `Page_Load` event

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FirstGridViewRow();
        }
```